# Build tool for Scala web application development

Tags: scala, tomcat7, java-ee-6, sbt

While working with Scala frameworks such as [Play!](http://playframework.org/) and [Lift](http://liftweb.net/) I was really amazed how these frameworks manage to create a full development stack from the source code up to the web application container (Jetty).

Right now I'm trying to configure a project on my own with the following features:

- Automatic deployment on Tomcat 7 (I'm not using Jetty as I require JEE6 support)
- WAR file packaging

Is it possible to do it with a build tool such as [SBT](http://www.scala-sbt.org) or [Maven](http://maven.apache.org)?

Note: My goal is to create my own project structure, not using an existing framework (even though I'm taking some ideas from them).

Comment: SBT is designed to do that. Take a look at: http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.7.7/docs/RunningSbt for some of its capabilities. Maven will let you do that as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a web plugin for SBT:

https://github.com/JamesEarlDouglas/xsbt-web-plugin

It gives you war packaging, but not automatic deployment (other than on Jetty, which it integrates, but which you don't have to use).

That said, I'd like to see a fork of that plugin that removes the Jetty dependency and adds an automatic external deployment option. Shouldn't be too hard to do.